# Unique Typescript syntax relating conditional generics and arrays

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have stumbled upon a certain Typescript syntax, which I find confusing. Here are two examples which were written by members of the Typescript team.

**Example 1**

```
type BoxedArray<T> = { array: T[] };
type Boxed<T> = T extends any[] ? BoxedArray<T[number]> : BoxedValue<T>;
type T21 = Boxed<number[]>;  // BoxedArray<number>;
```

[source](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html)

Here is how I'd naively read it:

```
// Boxed receives a type parameter - T = number[]
// Boxed passes BoxedArray an Array of T
// Therefore type T21 = BoxedArray<number[][]>
```

**Example 2**

```
type DeepReadonly<T> =
    T extends any[] ? DeepReadonlyArray<T[number]> :
    T extends object ? DeepReadonlyObject<T> :
    T;

interface DeepReadonlyArray<T> extends ReadonlyArray<DeepReadonly<T>> {}
```

[source](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316)

I understand that this syntax is somewhat similar to infer. I have seen it here and there, but I still don't really understand the structure, and couldn't find information about it.

Comment: The type `T[K]` is a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types), meaning `T[K]` is the type of value of the property of `T` at key `K`.  (Note that `T[K]` is not `T[]`.)  If `T` has a numeric index signature (like an array) then `T[number]` is the type of property stored at `T`'s numeric index.  If `T` is `Array<X>` then `T[number]` is `X`.

Comment: Thanks Jcalz, Your comment made the syntax very clear.  Why did you comment instead of answer?

Comment: "Why did you comment instead of answer?" Good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `T[K]` is a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types), meaning `T[K]` is the type of value of the property of `T` at key `K`. (Note that `T[K]` is not `T[]`.) If `T` has a numeric index signature (like an array) then `T[number]` is the type of property stored at `T`'s numeric index.  Specifically, if `T` is `Array<X>` then `T[number]` is `X`.  (That does lead to the confusing looking `string[][number]` being the same as `string`).  Hope that helps. Good luck!